# Why can't I feed a function as a default variable in a PHP function?

Tags: php, function

I have a function that returns a custom day-of-the-week, used in calculating custom week-periods.

What I am having a problem with is the default variable values when instantiating the function. I am using a *different* `function` to return the default value and this throwing an error.

When I call a simple function with something like:

```
function myFunction ($myVar = "test") { ... }
```

Then there is no problem.

As soon as I throw a `function` into the variable as a default, I get the following error:

```
[Tue Nov 03 15:00:41 2015] [error] [client 10.64.241.13] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting ')' in /var/www/service/test.php on line 6
```

Here is my function that is throwing this error in case you want an example:

```
function get_mod_week_day($day = date('N'), $hour = date('H') ) {

$myDay = null;

switch ($day) {

    case 1:
        $myDay = 5;
        break;
    case 2:
        $myDay = 6;
        break;
    case 3:
        $myDay = 7;
        break;
    case 4:
        $myDay = 1;
        break;
    case 5:
        $myDay = 2;
        break;
    case 6:
        $myDay = 3;
        break;
    case 7:
        $myDay = 4;
        break;
    default:
        $myDay = false;
}

return $myDay;

}
```

Is it impossible to call a `function` to return a default variable or is there some way to get around this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the docs [Function Arguments](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.default):

> The default value must be a constant expression, not (for example) a
>   variable, a class member or a function call.

Generally something similar to this would be done:

```
function get_mod_week_day($day=null, $hour=null) {
    $day  = is_null($day)  ? date('N') : $day;
    $hour = is_null($hour) ? date('H') : $hour;
}
```

Also, your `switch` seems lengthy seeing that you are just adding `4` or subtracting `3` from `$day`.

Answer (score 2):

The default value must be a constant expression, not (for example) a variable, a class member or a function call.